# Garry's Mod-Singleplayer Crash

Tags: garrys-mod

Now, before you downvote, this is different. I know it is an Addon that crashes my Gmod's Singleplayer. It says the addon, "importedswepskitz". When I look at the crash logs, I read what I can from it and I still can't find out what the addon is. When I disable all of my addons my Singleplayer loads (most of the time). What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of too many addons, or, more likely, conflicting addons. Try removing SWEP addons continuously one by one to spot the problem. This should fix it easily, but at the cost of time.